# Can DLLs linked via import libs be unloaded before the host DLL is unloaded?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllimport

I have a Foo.dll that links to a Bar.dll via Bar's import libs (Bar.lib). Foo.dll also delayloads Bar.dll so it's only loaded when it's first called. Now, if Foo.dll calls a function exported by Bar.dll so Bar.dll is loaded, can Bar.dll be unloaded before Foo.dll is unloaded from the process? The premise is that no other DLLs in the app's process has dependency on Bar.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to specify the [`/DELAY:UNLOAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdx9xk46.aspx) linker option and call the [`FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96c1b5cf.aspx) function.

See [Unloading a delay-loaded DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94zxdhbc.aspx) for more information.

Comment: To confirm, are you saying that Bar.dll cannot be unloaded before Foo.dll is unloaded from the process, unless `/DELAY:UNLOAD` and `FFunloadDelayLoadedFDLL` are utilized?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "cannot".  If the application calls `FreeLibrary` on Bar.dll, Bar.dll *will* be unloaded - it just won't be unloaded *safely*.

Comment: Good point. I should phrase my question more appropriately. Does Foo.dll hold a ref on Bar.dll such that, under normal circumstances, Bar.dll wouldn't get unloaded until Foo.dll is unloaded first and releases the aforementioned ref? I classify over/reckless use of `FreeLibrary` to not be a normal circumstance, i.e. app call `FreeLibrary` without corresponding `LoadLibrary` of a given DLL.

Comment: @lancery You are asking me to confirm something I didn't say. The answer to 'so are you saying' is always 'no'. I answered the question you asked. You're now asking a second question which really has nothing to do with the first one.

Comment: @EJP It's not clear to me if `FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL` is needed to unload Bar.dll. Based on Harry's comment, it seems like `FreeLibrary` would suffice.

Comment: @lancery I don't know why you wouldn't do it the way Microsoft intended. When you read the link I provided you will see that `FUnloadDelayLoadedDLL` calls `FreeLibrary` after doing some other stuff. If that other stuff isn't important why would they provide it?